# Manipulate SQL-Results on-query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

is there a way to manipulate SQL-Results "on-query" (replace value with something else...)?
Or is it "ok" to make a for-loop for all manipulations...

This is my python, so far

```
@region.cache_on_arguments()
def _import_details(self):
    scopes = Table('v_www_details',
                   self.metadata,
                   Column('uuid', VARCHAR(32), primary_key=True),
                   autoload=True,
                   schema='frs')

    query = self.session.query(scopes)\
        .order_by(scopes.c.lastname.asc())\
        .order_by(scopes.c.uuid.asc())\
        .order_by(scopes.c.profile.asc()).all()

    columns = scopes.c.keys()
    query = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in query]

    if query is not None:
        return query
    return False
```

The DB-View has a column "profile", containing text with `\n` - I need to convert all `\n` to `</li><li>` (for a HTML-List)

Comment: Perhaps handle rendering the value when... well rendering. You could btw replace `dict(zip(columns, row))` with `row._asdict()`.

Comment: Thanks, this was my first approach - but now another system use my saved values. I think its more comfortable to convert on import (and save this) - as converting on rendering and for another rest output...